# Managed Package: Code validation against patch org before actual deployment there

Tags: managed-package, deployment, validation, patch

After releasing main version of our managed package, we've decided to go ahead with bug fixing using patch org.

It's well known that patch org doesn't allow any addition or removal of artifacts. But from time to time our team members forget about this and push code with new or removed components to the git repo.

My original understanding was that by validating code and running tests against patch org (e.g. using ant migration tool and CI process) we would be able to detect such forbidden in patch scope actions and act appropriately.

But as it turns out you could deploy successfully to patch org even code that contains addition/removal of components. And actual enforcing of patch org restrictions happens only on package upload stage. But it's too late for us, since "bad" code has already been deployed to the patch org, i.e. some rollback/modification/clean up would be required to return org to "valid/normal" state.

Is there any way to enforce this "no addition or removal" rules at validation phase? What is the best practice when pushing code to patch org? What should we do if org has already been "polluted" with unsupported changes - how should we clean this up or rollback.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No automated way. Keeping a branch and specific team only working on branch with access May help. Ultimately process should help. Interested to see if someone knows another way

Comment: @Eric Currently I'm looking how to implement such validation at metadata files level using 'git diff' or whatever and then wrap this utility as a git hook or maybe will put it as a separate job in CI flow. The main challenge is to identify exactly what is allowed and what is not. With adding/removing files - it's clear. But when you add a field for instance, it's actually file modification, but not addition from git perspective - need somehow to handle such cases (or just forbid even to update anything inside objects folder). Hope I will not stuck with this approach.

Comment: @wesaw can you share your experiences? I'm facing the same problem, and considering a similar solution as you describe